# Scalability of Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-asio

I'm curious how far others have pushed Boost.Asio in terms of scalability. I am writing an application that may use close to 1000 socket objects, a handful of acceptor objects, and many thousand timer objects.  I've configured it such that there's a thread pool invoking `io_service::run` and use `strand`s in the appropriate places to ensure my handlers do not stomp on each other.

My platform is Red Hat Enterprise Linux with Boost 1.39, though I'm not opposed to upgrading to a more recent version of boost.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are using 1.39 on several Linux flavors for timers, network (both TCP and UDP), serial (20+ lines, two of which run at 500 kbps), and inotify events, and while we don't have many socket connections, we do have a few hundred async timers at any time. They are in production and they work well, for us. If I were you, I'd make up a quick prototype and performance-test it.

Boost [1.43](http://www.boost.org/users/news/version_1_43_0) claims a number of Linux-specific performance improvements in ASIO, but I am yet to benchmark them for our product.

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll do some measurements comparing Boost 1.39 to 1.43.

Answer (score 6):

I've used boost asio with a client / server where the server has several hundreds of concurrent connections all day long.  Each session does a lot of read/write operations for several hours each.  I would recommend using the latest version of boost asio.  I can't remember version 1.39 but I've had issues with older versions.   The current version of boost asio seems stable.

The software I'm talking about only runs on Windows I should mention as well though which differs from your situation.

Comment: Do you use multiple threads ? or just one big thread and asyncronous powers ?