# Boost asio::async_write sending thousands of small packets

Tags: c++, performance, networking, boost, boost-asio

In my application I have to send about 10 kb/s per connection. All packets are put in a `std::deque`. One thread iterates over the deque and sends packet data via `asio::async_write`.

My question is how much connections can I handle simultaneously in one thread? Can I send say 20 Mbytes/s?

Comment: For a related question, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025373/scalability-of-boost-asio

Comment: Answers on this question dont say can i send megabytes of small data chunks per second.

Comment: depending on the packet size, 20MB/sec/thread can be possible. you can always use a few threads and not one and make use of more than one core.

Comment: packets are between 100 - 500 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boost.Asio author Kohlhoff's [website](http://think-async.com/) has a [performance page](http://think-async.com/Asio/LinuxPerformanceImprovements). Looking at the graph of Linux-perf-11, he gets a throughput of ~300 Mb/sec with 1000 connections on a single CPU, which is way above your target of 10kb/sec per connection.